# Nicer way to compute means of a set with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

i am trying to compute a mean of two datasets, identified by a certain column. Here it is the column AA2. The trivial solution is to first identify the dataset, then compute the mean over that dataset. However this doesn't look nice in python. Is there a way numpy could do this for me?

my dataset:

> ```
>    Number       AA1   AA2 AA3   Atom     amou   mean_shift          stddev
>    187            ALA GLU LEU   C             1         119.47           0.00
>    187            ALA GLU LEU   O             1           8.42           0.00
>    188            ALA GLU LYS   C             1         120.67           0.00
>    188            ALA GLU LYS   O             1           9.11           0.00
>    777            ARG GLN ARG   C             1         117.13           0.00
>    777            ARG GLN ARG   O             1           8.48           0.00
> ```

what i want:

> ```
>    187             GLU    C             1        (119.47+120.67+117.13)/3 0.00
>    187             GLU    O             1          (8.42+9.11+8.48)/3           0.00
> ```

Edit:
I cleared up the example. The mean is computed over the column mean_shift, but only over those rows where the atom is the same. My (not so nice version) of this is:

```
i,j = 0,0
# iterate over all keys
for j in range(1, len(data_one)):
        key = data_two[j][3]
        aminoacid = data_two[j][5]
        print key, aminoacid
        stop
        keyeddata=[]
        for i in range(1, len(data_one)):
                if (data_one[i][2]==key):
                        keyeddata.append(data_one[i])
                print mean(keyeddata[6])
```

cheers,
and thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your question from your example. If you say that the column here is AA2 shouln't the first 4 entries belong to set 1(GLU) and the last two belong to set 2(GLN). And if so you need the mean for the 'mean' column in your case ?

Comment: I'm having trouble relating your desired output to your question -- how does "calculating the mean over AA2" translate to all the GLN and GLU/LYS rows disappearing? Can you give some pseudocode for the "trivial solution" so I can see what you mean? cheers.

Comment: still unclear what you want, but before the dataset isn't parsed into a any pythonic structure numpy cannot do anything on it. and what do you mean with "doesn't look nice in python"? If you want nice readable code, you probably want to wrap unnecesssary stuff into reusable classes such that the final code in main looks clean and readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it easily with structured arrays, like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Test data
data = [
   (187, "ALA","GLU", "LEU", "C", 1, 119.47, 0.00),
   (187, "ALA","GLU", "LEU", "O", 1, 8.42, 0.00),
   (188, "ALA","GLU", "LYS", "C", 1, 120.67, 0.00),
   (188, "ALA","GLU", "LYS", "O", 1, 9.11, 0.00),
   (777, "ARG","GLN", "ARG", "C", 1, 117.13, 0.00),
   (777, "ARG","GLN", "ARG", "O", 1, 8.48, 0.00),
   ]

# Structure definition
my_dtype = [
    ('Number',  'i4'),
    (  'AA1',   'a3'),
    (  'AA2',   'a3'),
    (  'AA3',   'a3'),
    ( 'Atom',   'a1'),
    ( 'amou',   'i4'),
    ( 'mean',   'f4'),
    ( 'stddev', 'f4')
           ]

a = np.array(data, dtype = my_dtype)
```

Now, with that `a` array, you can easily extract groups. First, let's find out the unique elements for a certain attribute:

```
>>> np.unique(a['AA2'])
array(['GLN', 'GLU'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Now, you can group data by matching the attribute. Eg:

```
# This gives you a mask
>>> a['AA2'] == 'GLN'
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
# that you can apply to the array itself
>>> a[a['AA2'] == 'GLN']
array([(777, 'ARG', 'GLN', 'ARG', 'C', 1, 117.12999725341797, 0.0),
       (777, 'ARG', 'GLN', 'ARG', 'O', 1, 8.4799995422363281, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('Number', '<i4'), ('AA1', '|S3'), ('AA2', '|S3'), ('AA3', '|S3'),
             ('Atom', '|S1'), ('amou', '<i4'), ('mean', '<f4'), ('stddev', '<f4')])
```

From there you can apply any calculation to an arbitrary attribute. Say, a mean of means:

```
>>> gln = a[a['AA2'] == 'GLN']
>>> gln['mean'].mean()
62.805000305175781
```

Edit:
Now, to select data following more than one criteria, keep into mind the previous `a['AA2'] == 'GLN'` example:

```
>>> a['Atom'] == 'C'
array([ True, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.logical_and(a['Atom'] == 'C', a['AA2'] == 'GLN')
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

# Which of course would give us the only row that fits:
>>> a[np.logical_and(a['Atom'] == 'C', a['AA2'] == 'GLN')]
array([(777, 'ARG', 'GLN', 'ARG', 'C', 1, 117.12999725341797, 0.0)], ...)
```

You will probably want to do some combinatorics on the criteria (using `itertools` or similar) to automate the process, and you may want also to have a look [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/routines.logic.html) to see the available logic functions in NumPy.

Comment: thats actually what i was looking for +1 for the nice examples. Can you add how i extend a mask to several columns?

Comment: Don't think "rows/columns" here. This is actually a 1D array! It's just that the type for each element is a structure like the one defined by `my_dtype`. Now, the mask is just a boolean array, meaning you can use boolean operations (and, or, xor...) to them. I'll update the answer to show how.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out Pandas? It is built on top of numpy and it has some very nice features for dealing with labeled data.

http://pandas.sourceforge.net/